# Table layout panel inc#

Tags: vb.net, tablelayoutpanel

I have to create dynamic table layout panel with some controls with auto sized rows and  and fixed columns size.
My problem is that i want to show whole checkbox text .
Any help
My code is

```
        Dim textBox2 As New CheckBox()
        textBox2.Text = "You forgot to add the ColumnStyles. Do this on a sample form first with the designer. Click the Show All Files icon in the Solution Explorer window. Open the node next to the form and double-click the Designer.vb file. "
        textBox2.AutoSize = True
        textBox2.Dock = DockStyle.Top
        ''  textBox2.Size = New Point(200, 90)
        Dim lbl1 As New Label()
        lbl1.Location = New Point(10, 10)
        lbl1.Text = "Yoer.vb"
        lbl1.AutoSize = True
        lbl1.Location = New Point(120, 50)
        lbl1.Dock = DockStyle.Top
        ''    dynamicTableLayoutPanel.Padding = New Padding(2, 17, 4, 5)
        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(lbl1, 0, 0)
        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(textBox2, 1, 0)
        Me.dynamicTableLayoutPanel.SetColumnSpan(textBox2, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want the table to size to the controls within it, then:

```
dynamicTableLayoutPanel.AutoSize = True
```

Comment: sir i want to show whole checkbox text in same column

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I stumbled across it and figured I'd throw my 2 cents in in case someone else comes along.

*Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with .NET 4.6. Functionality may differ between versions.*

The problem is that the really long text is not word-wrapping to fit within the table or form. Instead, it is set to `Dock = DockStyle.Top`. This will cause it to make a single line that continues on and gets clipped, similar to a single-line textbox.

If you want it to automatically word wrap, you'll need to use `Dock = DockStyle.Fill`. Now, this doesn't completely resolve the problem if your row or table isn't large enough to display the text. Since all of the rows are set to `AutoSize`, it will only do the bare minimum to fit the control vertically. It doesn't care if text gets clipped off. The end result, using your example code against a 6-column, 10-row table, is this:

[image: Initial Output]

Since there isn't a word wrap property, you'll need to manually fit it. Now, to do this, you'll need to change the row to be `Absolute` instead of `AutoSize`. To figure out how big to make it, you can pretty much rely on `PreferredSize`. This reveals a much wider `Width` than the existing regular `Width`. From that, we can determine how many lines it would take if we wrap it.

This is what my code ended up looking like:

```vb
  Dim h As Single = 0

  Dim chk As New CheckBox()
  chk.Text = "You forgot to add the ColumnStyles. Do this on a sample form first with the designer. Click the Show All Files icon in the Solution Explorer window. Open the node next to the form and double-click the Designer.vb file. "
  chk.AutoSize = True
  chk.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

  Dim lbl1 As New Label()
  lbl1.Text = "Yoer.vb"
  lbl1.AutoSize = True
  lbl1.Dock = DockStyle.Top

  dynamicTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(lbl1, 0, 0)
  dynamicTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(chk, 1, 0)
  dynamicTableLayoutPanel.SetColumnSpan(chk, 5)

  ' Find the preferred width, divide by actual, and round up.
  ' This will be how many lines it should take.
  h = Math.Ceiling(chk.PreferredSize.Width / chk.Width)
  ' Multiply the number of lines by the current height.
  h = (h * chk.PreferredSize.Height)
  ' Absolute size the parent row to match this new height.
  dynamicTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Item(0) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, h)
```

The changes included delaring a height variable, renaming the CheckBox variable, setting its Dock to Fill, removing the Location from lbl1, and adding in size calculation. The output:

[image: Changed Output]

This isn't perfect since the height includes the checkbox itself, and the checkbox takes up padding, so there can be too much or too little height calculated. There are other calculations that may need to be considered. But, this is a starting point.